# Redis Size Limit per individual cache

Tags: java, spring, redis

Redis can be used as a cache storage engine within Spring(boot) applications. However, it only allows to set an overall maxmemory size limit. **Is there a way to restrict individual RedisCaches in their size, either by number of elements or number of bytes stored in that (sub-)cache?**

Is there any wrapper-library that provides such functionality? Or is there perhaps an interface one could implement to easily achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own redis jar maintaining these restrictions and provide an interface to your main project. This will give you much more flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the same. I would suggest you use the Redisson client for this purpose.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public static class Application {

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    RedissonClient redisson() throws IOException {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useClusterServers()
              .addNodeAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:7004", "redis://127.0.0.1:7001");
        return Redisson.create(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
        Map<String, CacheConfig> config = new HashMap<String, CacheConfig>();

        // create "testMap" cache with ttl = 24 minutes and maxIdleTime = 12 minutes
        CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig(24*60*1000, 12*60*1000);
        // 100 entries 
        cacheConfig.setMaxSize(100);
        config.put("testMap", cacheConfig);
 
        return new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient, config);
    }

}
```

Comment: can i have multiple cacheconfig?? how to use

Comment: You can have a CacheConfig for each cache. Just create a new CacheConfig object with the TTL and maxIdleTime you want (and set any other config on it) and add it to the map passed to the RedissonSpringCacheManager constructor. Set the key in the map to the name of the cache.